# How to implement a pairs of values in Django Model

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a model for class Game. Here i need to create a pairs of:

1. pre-defined Platforms (i guess it'll be another class): Nintendo Switch, PlayStation 4, PlayStation 5 and so on.
2. release dates of the games on specific platforms. Because sometimes they are different across platforms.

So it'll be something like this on the view view:
Nintendo Switch - Jan 20, 2021

PlayStation 4 - Jan 20, 2021

Xbox One - Jan 20, 2021

Google Stadia - Jan 20, 2021

PlayStation 5 - Jan 20, 2021

Xbox Series X/S - Jan 20, 2021

And i want it to display correctly in admin panel and edit it there.

Tried to solve it, but haven't enough knowledge in the field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `__str__` function that shows the string representation of the object. It is also used in the admin panel

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.model})

class Platfrom(models.Model):
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
```